# Android OpenCV: color detection giving weird result

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I've just learnt how to detect a color from [OpenCV Java, Getting region of interest from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561455/opencv-java-getting-region-of-interest-from-image/45576051#45576051).

**Ultimately, I want to know how can I detect the AA battery(with and or without black tape)**

I'm now trying to detect the battery in the picture, but the battery is not fully black, and in turn giving me weird result:

[image]

I covered the battery with black tape and tried again the result seems better but it is detecting the battery in two separate sections:

[image]

**Code:**

```
private Bitmap findRoiBlack(Bitmap sourceBitmap) {
    Bitmap roiBitmap = null;
    Scalar green = new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255);
    Mat sourceMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(sourceBitmap, sourceMat);
    Mat roiTmp = sourceMat.clone();

    final Mat hsvMat = new Mat();
    sourceMat.copyTo(hsvMat);

    // convert mat to HSV format for Core.inRange()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(hsvMat, hsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

    Scalar lowerb = new Scalar(0, 0, 0);         // lower color border for BLACK
    Scalar upperb = new Scalar(180, 255, 30);      // upper color border for BLACK

    //Scalar lowerb = new Scalar(0, 0, 200);         // lower color border for WHITE
    //Scalar upperb = new Scalar(180, 255, 255);      // upper color border for WHITE
    Core.inRange(hsvMat, lowerb, upperb, roiTmp);   // select only blue pixels

    // find contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    List<RotatedRect> boundingRects = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(roiTmp, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // find appropriate bounding rectangles
    for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
        MatOfPoint2f areaPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
        RotatedRect boundingRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(areaPoints);

        double rectangleArea = boundingRect.size.area();

        // test min ROI area in pixels
        if (rectangleArea > 400) {
            Point rotated_rect_points[] = new Point[4];
            boundingRect.points(rotated_rect_points);

            Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(rotated_rect_points));

            // test vertical ROI orientation
            if (rect.height > rect.width) {
                Imgproc.rectangle(sourceMat, rect.tl(), rect.br(), green, 3);
            }
        }
    }

    roiBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceMat.cols(), sourceMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(sourceMat, roiBitmap);
    return roiBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way - is add color marker to battery. Other way is set solid, well distinguishable background for vertical channel of Your installation (may be even backlight - in this case You should find just black/low brightness object on white/high brightness background). If it's not possible and You have solid background - try to "invert" approach: don't try find battery (because it has many colors) - find background (because it has one solid color) - object with "non background" colors probably battery (and You have additional hints: battery is "vertical" rectangle with 1/4 proportions (AAA battery has 10.5 mm diameter and 44.6 mm length), it is approximately on the vertical center of image and has chromium-plated high brightness elements on top and bottom, etc.).